# meteor dbmongo find does not return all the elemnts

Tags: meteor, fullcalendar

I'm using meteor and javascript fullcalendar .

I'm trying to get the data from a dbmongo cursor.
But it's seem really randomly when I get the elements and when I don't

Here is my code :

```
events : function (start, end , timezone, callback) {
        var events = [];
        var eventsData = Events.find();

        eventsData.forEach(function(event) {
          events.push(event);
        });

        callback (events);
      }
```

This sits inside the isClient, in the jquery section.

Sometimes I get all the elements form the database and sometimes I don't.

Anybody have an idea on how to always get them?

Thanks

Comment: What does your Events publication look like? Or is this collection only client-side?